# Loop in R trying different features in logistic regression fit to find best auc score?

Tags: r, loops, machine-learning, tidyverse, logistic-regression

I'm using the Iris data set to fit a logistic regression. I want to fit each combination of features to see what I can get for the best AUC score.

For example, I would fit 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24 models.
This is essentially a permuting through every combination of features.
I would like to have it outputted in a table to see which combination gives me the best score.

**Top 3 rows of Dataset**

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

**Fitting one model**

Here is just fitting one of the models and getting the AUC

```
## make it binary classification

library(ROCR)
library(tidyverse)
iris.small <- iris %>%
  filter(Species %in% c("virginica", "versicolor"))

is.na(iris.small$Species) <- iris.small$Species == "setosa"
iris.small$Species <- factor(iris.small$Species)

## 75% of the sample size
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(iris.small))

## set the seed to make your partition reproducible
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(iris.small)), size = smp_size)

train <- iris.small[train_ind, ]
test <- iris.small[-train_ind, ]

mod1 <- glm(Species ~ .,
  data = train,
  family = binomial(link = "logit")
)

pred_probs <- predict(mod1, newdata = test, type = "response")


pred_obj <- ROCR::prediction(pred_probs, test$Species)
perf_obj <- ROCR::performance(pred_obj, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "fpr")

auc <- performance(pred_obj, measure = "auc")
auc <- auc@y.values[[1]]

print(auc)
```

**Intended output**
A table with the AUC scores for each fit. There would be two columns, the features in the fit and the AUC score.

Also, in general is this a good idea to do? Fitting 24 models may not seem very ideal, but I'm not sure how to determine which combinations of features is most optimal.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why 24 models? If you have 4 features, shouldn't be model1: 4 features, model2: 3 features, model3: 2 features and model4: 1 feature?

Comment: I would do a fit on each individual feature: which would be 4 models. And then a fit on every combination of two of the features, and so on so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I list the combinations I got.

```
library(plyr)
#Index
a1 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(1:4,1)))
a2 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(1:4,2)))
a3 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(1:4,3)))
a4 <- as.data.frame(t(combn(1:4,4)))
#Cols contains the combinations
Cols <- do.call(rbind.fill,list(a1,a2,a3,a4))
```

Then we have a way to allocate the variables by index:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4
1   1 NA NA NA
2   2 NA NA NA
3   3 NA NA NA
4   4 NA NA NA
5   1  2 NA NA
6   1  3 NA NA
7   1  4 NA NA
8   2  3 NA NA
9   2  4 NA NA
10  3  4 NA NA
11  1  2  3 NA
12  1  2  4 NA
13  1  3  4 NA
14  2  3  4 NA
15  1  2  3  4
```

The next code computes what you need:

```
## make it binary classification
library(ROCR)
library(tidyverse)
iris.small <- iris %>%
  filter(Species %in% c("virginica", "versicolor"))
is.na(iris.small$Species) <- iris.small$Species == "setosa"
iris.small$Species <- factor(iris.small$Species)
## 75% of the sample size
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(iris.small))
## set the seed to make your partition reproducible
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(iris.small)), size = smp_size)
train <- iris.small[train_ind, ]
test <- iris.small[-train_ind, ]
#Now create a list
List <- list()
#Iterate over all posible values of Cols
for(i in 1:dim(Cols)[1])
{
  #Variables
  #Define target and covariates
  vals <- as.vector(na.omit(t(Cols[i,])))
  target <- "Species"
  vars <- names(iris.small)[vals]
  #Create formulas
  string <- paste(target,'~', paste(vars, collapse= "+"))
  fmla <- as.formula(paste(target,'~', paste(vars, collapse= "+")))
  #Model 
  mod1 <- glm(formula = fmla,
              data = train,
              family = binomial(link = "logit"))
  pred_probs <- predict(mod1, newdata = test, type = "response")
  
  
  pred_obj <- ROCR::prediction(pred_probs, test$Species)
  perf_obj <- ROCR::performance(pred_obj, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "fpr")
  
  auc <- performance(pred_obj, measure = "auc")
  auc <- auc@y.values[[1]]
  #Save results
  output <- data.frame(Model=string,auc=auc)
  #Feed into list
  List[[i]] <- output
}
#Format as dataframe
DFResult <- do.call(rbind,List)
```

You will get:

```
                                                         Model       auc
1                                       Species ~ Sepal.Length 0.7852564
2                                        Species ~ Sepal.Width 0.5128205
3                                       Species ~ Petal.Length 0.9903846
4                                        Species ~ Petal.Width 1.0000000
5                           Species ~ Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width 0.7403846
6                          Species ~ Sepal.Length+Petal.Length 1.0000000
7                           Species ~ Sepal.Length+Petal.Width 1.0000000
8                           Species ~ Sepal.Width+Petal.Length 0.9935897
9                            Species ~ Sepal.Width+Petal.Width 1.0000000
10                          Species ~ Petal.Length+Petal.Width 1.0000000
11             Species ~ Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length 1.0000000
12              Species ~ Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Width 1.0000000
13             Species ~ Sepal.Length+Petal.Length+Petal.Width 1.0000000
14              Species ~ Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width 1.0000000
15 Species ~ Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width 1.0000000
```